# How to configure github status avatars

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration

I'd like to provide a custom avatar URL in github based on our current CI test status.

I'm using the following curl command to set the target commits' status successfully:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Authorization: token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://api.github.com/repos/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/statuses/$(git rev-parse HEAD) -d "{
  \"state\": \"pending\",
  \"target_url\": \"${BUILD_URL}console\",
  \"description\": \"${BRANCH_NAME}\",
  \"context\": \"Jenkins Branch Test\",
}"
```

However, when I add the avatar URL to the github POST it returns an error.

I don't think the API accepts avatar_url, but I've found no other solution for specifying branch test status avatars.

Appreciate any help,
Shaun

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the error into your question? There are many reasons an error might occur.

Answer (score 1):

This is isn't possible via the status or check api.

Apparently for status, checks & check suite api, the avatar for the Github App is picked up and displayed.

Please correct me if I'm mistaken.